# How to delete a line in a Memo according to the quantity of numbers in the line?

Tags: delphi

Good night, I have a memo that receives several strings and in many lines, I want to delete the lines that contain less or more than seven (7) numbers, leaving only the lines that have exactly seven (7) numbers. I'm trying with a code only every Memo is erased.

```
var
  cont, N: Integer;
begin
  cont := 0;
  N := Length(GetStrNumber(Memo2.Lines.Strings[cont]));
  //N = quantity of numbers on the line in the Memo

  while (cont <= Memo2.Lines.Count  - 1)  do
    if N <> 7 then  //If N is different from 7 then delete the line
    begin
      Memo2.Lines.Delete(cont)
    end
    else
      Inc(cont);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are retrieving the count only for the 1st line. You need to perform the retrieval inside the loop for every line, eg:

```pascal
var
  cont, N: Integer;
begin
  cont := 0;
  while cont < Memo2.Lines.Count do
  begin
    N := Length(GetStrNumber(Memo2.Lines.Strings[cont]));
    if N <> 7 then
      Memo2.Lines.Delete(cont)
    else
      Inc(cont);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The loop should be reversed othevise it will skip checking of some lines due the fact that once you Delete one line all following lines will be shifted so their index position will be lowered by one..

Comment: @SilverWarior that would be true if `cont` were incremented on every iteration, but in this example it is incremented only on iterations that don't delete, hence no lines are skipped when a deletion does occur

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this so take it for what it's worth.
Your assignment to N is outside your loop, so it is only checked once, for line 0.
So if it doesn't equal 7 your loop will delete all rows